# Show chart if button clicked, close it if clicked again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code from a plugin to display a chart and I want to only show this chart if a button is clicked, and close it again and if the button is clicked again. the code for the chart is this:

```
$(function(){
  $("#doughnutChart").drawDoughnutChart([
    { title: "Tokyo",         value : 100,  color: "#2C3E50" },
    { title: "San Francisco", value:  80,   color: "#FC4349" },
    { title: "New York",      value:  70,   color: "#6DBCDB" },
    { title: "London",        value : 50,   color: "#F7E248" },
    { title: "Sydney",        value : 40,   color: "#D7DADB" },
    { title: "Berlin",        value : 20,   color: "#FFF" }
  ]);
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="doughnutChart" class="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some simple jQuery will do the trick.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("button").click(function(){
         $("#doughnutChart").toggle();
     });
});
```

This should show/hide your chart.

**Edit**

Add the following over your code in the Fiddle. Basically replace line 307 in the javascript with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#something").click(function(){
         if($('#doughnutChart').is(':visible')) {
             $(".doughnutChartwrap").hide();
             $(".doughnutChartwrap").html("<div id=\"doughnutChart\" class=\"chart\"></div>");
         }
         else{
             $("#doughnutChart").drawDoughnutChart([
                 { title: "Tokyo",         value : 100,  color: "#2C3E50" },
                 { title: "San Francisco", value:  80,   color: "#FC4349" },
                 { title: "New York",      value:  70,   color: "#6DBCDB" },
                 { title: "London",        value : 50,   color: "#F7E248" },
                 { title: "Sydney",        value : 40,   color: "#D7DADB" },
                 { title: "Berlin",        value : 20,   color: "#FFF" }
             ]);
             $(".doughnutChartwrap").show();
         }
     });
});
```

Comment: and should I wrap that code on my question inside of the toggle?? like this? `$("#doughnutChart").toggle(MY CODE HERE);` because I tried to put this code you gave me above it and it doesn't work :\

Comment: I figured it out. I wrapped `#doughnutChart` inside of a another div as a toggler

Comment: Still, it the chart has na animation and I can't see it now because the animation alreay loaded it while the div was hidden

Comment: In that case it may be smarter to put your code within an if statement that checks the visibility of the div. If it's visible, then $("#doughnutChart").hide and clear the innerHTML of the div. If it's invisible, then $("#doughnutChart").show and reload the chart function if you can. That way, the animation is called on the button click.

Comment: Can you add a bit more code to the fiddle? Just so I can fiddle with it?